# Gateway artifact generator wso2 apim class not found

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I've recently started working with WSO2 APIM and am having trouble with the Gateway Artifact Generator. It seems to be throwing a Class Not Found error. Is this a known issue or am I missing a specific library or configuration? I've checked the classpath and everything seems fine. I am using 4.1.0 apim.

Comment: How did you download the APIM pack ? Did you get this in the fresh pack or after doing some changes ?